# Download certain user's files from SharePoint online

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

My company has buisness account and domain like `\<company>.sharepoint.com`
So each employee has his own OneDrive space like
`\<company>-my.sharepoint.com`
We have special account to manage our documents that are stored on it's own onedrive like this
[files stored on emploee onedrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXp83.png)

I tried SharePoint CSOM, Microsoft Graph API and SharePointAPI. Using any of it i can get file-related data like name, last change date etc.
But when I try to download it using something like this:

```
var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByUrl(<url to file>);
var fileStream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I have exception

> File Not Found

Even using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer i can't reach my files

also using SharePoint CSOM I can download file from
<company>.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Is there a way to download files directly from employee documents library, or it's forbbiden and i should move all files to SharePoint 'Communication site' documents?

Comment: have you checked if the client context that you initialize has access to a user's one drive - Documents docLibrary?

Comment: Yes I`m prety shure it hava acces becouse I used my own login and password and tried to download file

Comment: in case you are using your account, you have access to your own document library.
you cannot access different people's document libraries without adding permissions to your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solwed the problem by using Azure Active Directory App like in this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service